# Problema React Router Dom, ruta anidada

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
const Dashboard = () => {
    const persona = useSelector((state) => state.persona);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleSalir = () => {
        return undefined;
    };

    if (persona == undefined) {
        console.log(`persona`, persona);
        return <LinearProgress />
    } else {
        if (persona.apiKey == undefined) {
            console.log(`personaApiKey`, persona.apiKey);
            return <Navigate replace to={"/login"}></Navigate>;
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Navbar bg="light" variant="light">
                        <Container>
                            <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Envios</Navbar.Brand>
                            <Nav className="me-auto">
                                <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink> |
                                <NavLink to="/envios">Envios</NavLink> |
                                <NavLink to="/nuevo">Nuevo envio</NavLink> |
                            </Nav>
                            <Button onClick={handleSalir} style={{ float: "right" }}>
                                Salir
                            </Button>
                        </Container>
                    </Navbar>

                    <Outlet></Outlet>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
};
export default Dashboard;
```

Buenas, tengo este código, el problema es que al apretar en el link  de nuevo envío en vez de mostrarme solo el componente nuevoEnvío me muestra el componente envíos y también el componente nuevoEnvío.

```
function App() {
  const store = createStore(
    reducer,
  );

  return (
    <Container>
      <Card>
        <Card.Body>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <Provider store={store}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                  <Routes>
                    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                    <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}>
                      <Route index element={<Home />} />
                      <Route path="envios" element={<Envios />}>
                        <Route path="nuevo" element={<NuevoEnvio />} />
                      </Route>
                    </Route>
                    {/* <Route path="*" element={<p>NO SE HALLO</p>}></Route> */}
                    <Route
                      path="*"
                      element={<Navigate replace to={"/"}></Navigate>}
                    />
                  </Routes>
                </BrowserRouter>
              </Provider>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Quiero que solo me muestre un componente o el otro y que la ruta sea anidada ej: .com/envios/nuevo
Intente hacer que la ruta no sea hijo pero me muestra la ruta como .com/nuevo en vez de .com/envios/nuevo, espero una solución!

No se que mas poner pero la página me pide que siga poniendo y no se que poner entonces sigo escribiendo bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensaya agregando la propiedad `exact` asi:

```
<Route exact path="envios" element={<Envios />}>
    <Route exact path="nuevo" element={<NuevoEnvio />} />
</Route>
```

Comment: Pipe, gracias por la respuesta pero me sigue mostrando ambos componentes, probe tambien con outlet y nada. Lo que en realidad quiero es que el componente envío se esconda y el componente nuevoEnvio sea el que se muestre solamente

Comment: Si, eso se supone que es lo que debería pasar con la solución que te puse. No tiene sentido que te aparezcan los 2 si las rutas son exactas... seguro que pusiste el `exact` como era?